# sliding array values

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, 2048

I'm trying to recreate the game 2048 in vb and I'm struggling with figuring out how to get the values in an array to slide together.

I'm trying to do this in a single dimensional array before I task myself with the full thing

for example if I have an array of

```
[0,2,0,4]
```

I need to figure out how I can step through each number, check if there is a 0 behind it so that the array would become

```
[2,4,0,0]
```

but I'm struggling with figuring out how to check all the values behind a number in the array

I'm only trying the slide left function at the moment just so I can take things slowly, does anyone have any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: Is it required that the array keeps the same length?

Comment: Yes, the array represents one of the rows on the game grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with LINQ:

```
Dim a = {0, 2, 0, 4}
a = a.Where(Function(x) x <> 0).Concat(a.Where(Function(x) x = 0)).ToArray()

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", a)) ' outputs 2,4,0,0
```

The first `Where` gets all the non-zero elements. The `Concat` concatenates the result of that with (all the zero elements), thus maintaining the length of the data, and the `.ToArray()` converts the result back to an array.

Comment: This worked brilliantly, thank you for the elegant solution!

Comment: I guess you saw that you can get the "slide right" by swapping the `<>` and `=`.

Comment: I used the array reverse function for it, but your way is probably much better

Answer (score 1):

Old classic `For Each` which loop array only ones.

```vb
Dim previousRow As Integer() = { 0, 2, 0, 4 }
Dim newRow As Integer() = { 0, 0, 0, 0 }

Dim newRowIndex As Integer = 0
For Each previousValue In previousRow 
    If previousValue = 0 Then Continue For

    newRow(newRowIndex) = previousValue
    newRowIndex += 1
Next
```

Will return `{ 2, 4, 0, 0 }`

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code:

```
dim arr1, arr2,

foreach [value in array]
    if ( value is not 0 ) 
    then add to arr1
    else add to arr2

concat arr1, arr2
```